# parseFloat turns thousands into single digit -- unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a weird situation going on.

I have an array of objects... each object has a `.value.rate` field, and I am adding them all together.

For Example,
`let quoteSelections = ["$4,000", "$0.00"]`

To do this, I am using the useEffect hook in react - each time the rate changes, it adds it up. The problem is, anything larger than a number with a hundreds placement revers back to single digits - so "4000" becomes the number `4`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (quoteSelections.length > 0) {
      let rateTotal = quoteSelections
        .map((selec) => parseFloat(selec.value.rate.slice(1)))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      if (rateTotal > 0) {
        setEstimate(rateTotal);
      } else {
        setEstimate(0);
      }
    }
  }, [quoteSelections]);
```

If `quoteSelections = ["$400", "$0.00"]` It works fine. But anything above 999 causes it to revert back to single digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the comma in your strings, `parseFloat` does not know how to handle this, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#description):

> If parseFloat encounters a character other than a plus sign (+), minus sign (- U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), numeral (0–9), decimal point (.), or exponent (e or E), it returns the value up to that character, ignoring the invalid character and characters following it.

I'm assuming your working input does not contain the dollar sign, because that would also cause it to not work.